# Typescript return value or curried function

Tags: javascript, typescript, currying

Given the following Typescript code, I get an error

`TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'AddReturnType' has no compatible call signatures.`

Why doesn't `AddReturnType` work with that call?

```
type AddReturnType = number | ((arg0: number) => number);
function add(x: number, y?: number) : AddReturnType {
    if (!y) {
        return (val) => val + y;
    }
    return x + y;
}

add(1)(2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript can't determine whether you're returning a `number` or function, and only one of the two options is callable. Make the two function signatures separate:

```
function add(x: number): (number) => number;
function add(x: number, y: number): number;
function add(x, y?) {
    if (!y) {
        return (val) => val + y;
    }
    return x + y;
}

add(1)(2);
```

That said, shouldn't it be `val + x`?

Comment: It should.  That was a typo on my part.

Comment: That implementation still gives errors that `x`, `y`, and `val` all have an implicit `any` type.

Comment: @BrandonOlivier I haven't written it out `--strict`-ly, you'll have to add more explicit types if you have noImplicitAny enabled